# How to validate a form with the Play Framework 2 using javascript, i.e. jquery.ajax, and pass the rendered response to the view?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, playframework

I am using The play framework 2.1.3 and have a question concerning form validation using jquery and ajax. I have followed the advice in this post (http://franzgranlund.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/play-framework-2-0-javascriptrouter-in-java/) for setting up JavaScript routing and that part is working great! I need help with the second part, returning a rendered form containing error messages and displaying it on my page. I have created the following example to illustrate my problem.

The routes file looks as follows:

```
# AJAX calls
POST    /validateForm               controllers.Application.validateForm()

# JavaScript Routing
GET     /assets/javascripts/routes  controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()
```

The Application Controller looks as follows:

```
private static Form<User> form = Form.form(User.class);

public static Result validateForm() {       
    Form<User> boundForm = form.bindFromRequest();
            
    if (boundForm.hasErrors()) {            
        return badRequest(user_form.render(boundForm));
    } else {            
        return ok();
    }
}

public static Result javascriptRoutes() {       
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
        return ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes", controllers.routes.javascript.Application.validateForm()
    ));
}
```

Without getting too technical, I am using Twitter Bootstrap to render my forms so I have created the following view element (see this post for more information [Form validation and form helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212085/form-validation-and-form-helper)) which is rendered by the validateForm action and returns it to the calling jquery.ajax() .

```
@(userForm: Form[User])

@import helper._
@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapInput.f) }

@form(routes.Application.createUser(), 'id -> "createUserForm") {
    <fieldset>
    <legend>New User</legend>
        @inputText(userForm("name"), 'class -> "form-control", 'placeholder -> "First Name")
        @inputText(userForm("surname"), 'class -> "form-control", 'placeholder -> "Last Name")
        <button id="createUserBtn" type="button" class="btn">Create User</button>
    </fieldset>                         
}
```

I am using jquery and my javascript file looks as follows. For the purposes of this question, assume validation fails and a badRequest is returned.

```
$("#createUserBtn").click(function() {
    jsRoutes.controllers.Application.validateForm().ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#createUserForm").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            // something here
        },
        error: function(response) {
            $("#createUserForm").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Without going into too much detail on the view, I correctly include the JavaScript file in the view and there is an element called #createUserForm.

The communication between client-side and server-side seems to be working great, however, I am unable to load the rendered view element contained in the response onto the page through .html(response). So, how does one accomplish this? Where have I gone wrong? I am fairly new to many of these concepts and would appreciate any helpful input. Thanks.

## UPDATE:

Two changes changes will allow this code to work beautifully. (1) Since we are replacing the entire form, including the button, we need to make use of the jQuerys .on() to handle the button click event. (2) Calling responseText property will correctly return the html contained within the result.

```
$(document).on("click", "#createUserBtn", function() {
    jsRoutes.controllers.Application.validateForm().ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#createUserForm").serialize(),
         success: function(response) {
            // something here
        },
        error: function(response) {
            $("#createUserForm").html(response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Any comments? How would you do this better?